# Are C++14 digit separators allowed in user defined literals?

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer, user-defined-literals, digit-separator

While clang compiles the following line, g++ 6.1 complains about the digit separator (see [live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7c86b6ff59d95d7b)):

```
auto time = 01'23s;
```

Which compiler, if any, is correct according to the C++14 standard (N3796)?

Otherwise, is allowing digit separators (§2.14.2) just an implementation detail in the user-defined literals (§2.14.8) of the `<chrono>` library (§20.12.5.8)? IMHO it should be not, since these literals are defined on `unsigned long long` parameters.

I remember Howard Hinnant using `10'000s` as an example during his [CppCon 2016 talk "A `<chrono>` tutorial"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M&index=64&list=PLHTh1InhhwT7J5jl4vAhO1WvGHUUFgUQH) (at about 42 minutes in his talk).

---

(Please note, that I did not intend to code "1 minute and 23 seconds", which is **only correct by accident**, since the octal literal 0123 is 64 + 16 + 3 == 83. For that purpose I should write

```
auto time = 1min + 23s;
```

but that possible misleading interpretation is not part of the question.)

Comment: It appears to be a library bug and should be reported. My limited experiments suggest that `libstdc++` defines the wrong kind of literal operator, taking template non-type parametes `template<char ... _Digits>` instead of `unsigned long long`. But this isn't required by the standard, and it's doing the wrong this. They have left out the `operator""s(unsigned long long)` operator, I think this is the basic underlying issue. (They do have `operator""s(long double)`, as required)

Comment: The bug was reported here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69905  (Somebody else posted this link, then deleted their comment, but I think it is the correct link!)

Comment: @Aaron McDaid: I deleted that comment, when including it in my own answer (see below).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you look at the grammar, *user-defined-integer-literal* can be *octal-literal ud-suffix*, and *octal-literal* is defined as either `0` or *octal-literal ’<sub>opt</sub> octal-digit*.

> N4140 §2.14.8
>
> *user-defined-literal*:
>
> - *user-defined-integer-literal*
> - [...]
>
> *user-defined-integer-literal*:
>
> - *octal-literal ud-suffix*
> - [...]

​

> N4140 §2.14.2
>
> *octal-literal*:
>
> - `0`
> - *octal-literal ’<sub>opt</sub> octal-digit*

So `01'23s` is a perfectly valid literal.

Answer (score 5):

WLOG for decimal literals:

[[lex.ext]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ext):

> *user-defined-integer-literal: 
>
>       **decimal-literal** ud-suffix*

[[lex.icon]](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon):

> *decimal-literal*: 
>      *nonzero-digit* 
>      ***decimal-literal  `’`<sub>opt</sub> 
>   digit***

I.e. yes, digit separators are allowed in UDLs.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a bug in GCC's implementation of the `<chrono>` library, as @Aaron McDaid suggested. There is a (currently unconfirmed) bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69905

GCC's libstdc++ implements two signatures for `std::chrono_literals`:

```
constexpr chrono::duration<long double>
operator""s(long double __secs)
{ return chrono::duration<long double>{__secs}; }

template <char... _Digits>
  constexpr chrono::seconds
  operator""s()
  { return __check_overflow<chrono::seconds, _Digits...>(); }
```

The template version giving the error is not required by the standard.
When adding

```
constexpr chrono::seconds
operator""s(unsigned long long __secs)
{ return chrono::seconds{__secs}; }
```

to the `<chrono>` header (of my local installation) the error dissappears.

However, GCC's library implementers may have left out this version on purpose, so they can prevent an unwanted unsigned to signed conversion, since seconds are defined as

```
typedef duration<int64_t> seconds;
```

---

Edit:

As recently pointed out by Jonathan Wakely in the comments of the bug report, 
the implementation was chosen by design in connection with an
[open Library Working Group issue](https://wg21.link/lwg2383), but did not take digit separators into account.

Comment: The issue is that the standard requires compile-time overflow checking, but using a cooked literal operator doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: I don't understand what a "cooked" operator is, @T.C.. Do you mean that the "straightforward" `unsigned long long` overload isn't able to do that checking at compile time? And therefore the template is required?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid Correct. "cooked" = one taking an `unsigned long long`; "raw" = one that takes characters.