# How do user-defined literals play together with digit separator?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, user-defined-literals, digit-separator

I was just modifying an old example of my code by adding a *digit separator* to a user-defined literal, parsed by a variadic template:

```
namespace lits {
  // helper for 1 arg
  template<char C> int bin();  // common
  template<>       int bin<'1'>() { return 1; } // spec.
  template<>       int bin<'0'>() { return 0; } // spec.
  // helper 2 or more args
  template<char C, char D, char... ES>
  int bin() {
    return bin<C>() << (sizeof...(ES)+1) | bin<D,ES...>() ;
  }
  // operator"" _bin
  template<char...CS> int operator"" _bin()
    { return bin<CS...>(); };
}
int main() {
  using namespace lits;
  int number = 1000'0000_bin; // <<< I added a ' here
}
```

Boy, was I surprised when by *g++6.2.0* tried to instantiate `bin<'\''>`. It tried to pass the `'` as a `char` to my template `template<char...CS> int operator"" _bin()`! I tried it with *clang++-3.9* and *msvc++-19.00*, same complaint, which really makes me sceptical.

I have the feeling that that may not the right behavior. I would have understood it if my literal was in quotes, say `"1000'0000"_bin`, but this form does not exist for template operator"", right?

Am I to expect the digit separator `'` in my template user-literal operators, too, now?

**Update 1:** in case the `'` is ok:

One could use the digit-sep as a sep for all sort of things, say, complex numbers. Would the behavior of `52.84'67.12_i' for *52.84+67.12i* be well defined?'

**Udpdate 2:** As reaction some of the comments. The following compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;

namespace lits {
  // helper
  template<char C> string sx() { return string{}+C; }
  // helper 2 or more args
  template<char C, char D, char... ES>
  string sx() {
    return sx<C>() + sx<D,ES...>();
  }
  // operator"" _sx
  template<char...CS> string operator"" _sx()
  { return sx<CS...>(); };
}
int main() {
  using namespace lits;
  std::cout << 10000000_sx << '\n';
  std::cout << 10'000'000_sx << '\n';
  std::cout << 0x00af_sx << '\n';
  std::cout << 0x0'c'0'a'f_sx << '\n';
  std::cout << 007_sx << '\n';
  std::cout << 0b01_sx << '\n';
  // the following do not work:
  //std::cout << 0b0a8sh3s1_sx << '\n';
  //std::cout << "abcde"_sx << '\n';
}
```

And the output is:

```
10000000
10'000'000
0x00af
0x0'c'0'a'f
007
0b01
```

Which means that the template gets *all* the characters: prefixes and digit separators -- all of them. (g++-6.2.0)

As @krzaq's answer suggests, it seems this is the plan of the Std, so one can rely on it.

Comment: Consider how `01` and `1` mean exactly the same thing when interpreted as `int`, yet you may want `01_bin` and `1_bin` interpreted differently (a bit string of length 2 vs. a bit string of length 1). Regardless of what the standard says (that's answered already), it makes sense that you receive the exact spelling that the user used. It's up to you to decide which spelling differences matter and which don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, yes. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40262320/2456565), digit separators are legal members of user defined integer literals.

And the template integer literal is defined as:

> N4140 § 2.13.8 [lex.ext] / 3
>
> Otherwise (*S* contains a literal operator template), *L* is treated
>   as a call of the form
>
> ```
> operator "" X <’c1’, ’c2’, ... ’ck’>()
> ```
>
> where *n* is the source character sequence c<sub>1</sub>c<sub>2</sub>...c<sub>k</sub>. [ *Note:* The sequence
>   c<sub>1</sub>c<sub>2</sub>...c<sub>k</sub> can only contain characters
>   from the basic source character set. —*end note* ]

There's not a word about removing separators.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I read [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) the separator is allowed only when you get the literal as a number, not when the operator is a raw literal. That means you will get rid of the separator by the compiler if the operator parameter type is `unsigned long long`, not if it's one of the raw ones that get C-string or char.

Comment: That sort of would be amazing! One could use the digit-sep as a sep for all sort of things, say, complex numbers. Would the behavior of `52.84'67.12_i' for *52.84+67.12i* be well defined?'

Comment: Looking in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40265094/4299382) answer in the linked question seems like this is consistent with the `chrono` behavior described there, where raw literal operator gets the separator as is while the cooked one (getting `ull`) ignores it. Unfortunately, I can't find clear enough reference in the standard text.

Comment: If `<chrono>` uses it, @howard-hinnant often watches this site. Maybe He'll see it.